# Equation renders in preview mode but not when posted on SE site

Tags: bug, mathjax

I answered a question on OR SE ([here](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/10475/3464)) and the equations do render in preview mode, but not when the answer is submitted. The same problem persists on different devices and browsers.

Comment: Have you [read the guide?](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're encountering the same issue that I've had [before](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30248/602049) on the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) SE site. The problem is that the `\tag` values are *global* (within a MathJax namespace) in scope. In preview mode, your answer is by itself (at least in terms of an appropriate namespace), so your tags work correctly there. However, after you posted, since the answer above you (with the default sorting order) is using the same 2 tags that you do, then MathJax doesn't properly handle your tag values.

This can be confirmed by clicking on your 2 referenced links, to notice they go to the equations in the answer above instead of yours. Also, by changing the sort order to "Date modified (newest first)", your answer then appears above the other one, with your equations now rendering correctly (and with the other answer having the problem instead), as shown below:

> [image: Answer of the OP showing correctly when it is on top instead]

A simple solution (to avoid this problem for your posts and/or it affecting any other ones on the page), that I've used myself, is to just ensure the tags are different from those anywhere else on the page. In your particular case, for example, you can change your `\tag1` to something like `\tag{1A}` (and `\tag2` accordingly), along with your corresponding `\eqref` statements.